# The Lebesgue measure problem

Tags: measure-theory

We need to prove that the Cartesian product of two sets $A,B∈\mathbb{R}$ is a measurable set on $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. $A,B∈L(\mathbb{R})$ (measurable by Lebesgue in $\mathbb{R}$) implies $A*B∈L(\mathbb{R}^2)$.
I figured out how to write that $A$ and $B$ are measurable by Lebesgue: $∀ε>0,  ∃A⊂E:μ(AΔE)<ε$ and similarly for $B$. And then how to be I can't think of.

Comment: It seems that this has been asked and answered before: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=cartesian+product+measurable